# Display results after option selected

Tags: php, html

How can I create an SQL statement that will only show the options based upon one of the three options selected (C/E/W). At the moment, it just shows every result.

Also, how do i do this so the result will drop below once a C/E/W has been selected without the need for a submit button?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<select id="combobox">
    <option value="Central" id="C">C</option>
    <option value="East" id="E">E</option>
    <option value="West" id="W">W</option>
</select>
</p>
</div>
<div>
<?php 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ROOMS"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if ($result == FALSE) die ("could not execute statement $query<br />");

    echo "<table>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['roomCode'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Park'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Capacity'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Style'] . "</td><td>" . $row['dataProjector'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Whiteboard'] . "</td><td>" . $row['OHP'] . "</td><td>" . $row['wheelchairAccess'] . "</td><td>" . $row['lectureCapture'] . "</td></tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";

    mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: You are going to need some javascript and ajax to do this..